# mongoose: Finding an id that is nested?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I'm sorry if this is a repetitive question, but I'm yet to find a solution after scouring the internet for hours :( . I have a database for storing tasks ( a todo list app ) and then I have another so you can make custom todo list with different todos ect...

this database stores the name and an array of the items of the other schema with the specific todos.

```
const listSchema = {
    name: String,
    items: [itemSchema]
}
```

the database looks like this:

```
[
  {
    _id: 5ea083694f1d7d0db432b939,
    name: 'home',
    items: [ [Object], [Object] ],
    __v: 2
  }
]
```

and in the items array it looks like this:

```
[
  { _id: 5ea083764f1d7d0db432b93a, name: 'some todo', check: false },
  {
    _id: 5ea08391ab923b36780429ee,
    name: 'some other todo',
    check: false
  }
]
```

What I want to do is find and update by a specific id in the items array, I have the variables

```
 const id = req.body.check // in a for loop and gets id of the specific item 
 const titleName = req.body.titleName; // gets the title name of the parent object of the items array
```

and it needs to find using the titleName and the id so that I can update the "check: false" so that it's "check: true"

.
.
.

**Found Solution:**

```
 List.updateOne({"items._id" : id}, {"$set": {"items.$.check": true}})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use findOneAndUpdate(filter, update)  of mongoose

```
const id = req.body.id;
 const titleName = req.body.titleName; 
collectionName.findOneAndUpdate({"items.id": id, "name": titleName}, {"check": true})
```